# Name changed in passport, do I have to have my US visa changed as well?

Tags: usa, us-visa

I just renewed my Bajan passport with my new last name (for example "Keith Robert Stone" changed to "Keith Robert Stone Foster"). Do I have to change my US Visa to match my new name? I still have 7 years left on my visa.